# Правописание матерного слова в качестве междометия

Tags: орфография, обсценная-лексика

В соц. сети с друзьями возник нешуточный диспут на тему правописания слова "бля*ь" в качестве междометия. Большинство уверено, что в этом случае оно пишется через "т". Хотелось бы узнать мнение специалистов по этому вопросу, а то поисковики по большей части выдают мнение, не подкрепленное  ничем, кроме субъективных умозрений.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Подберите проверочное слово. Там чётко слышится *д*. И "в качестве междометия" употребляется именно это слово, следовательно, нет причин менять его орфографию. 
А ещё мне мысль понравилась: если человек матерится, это просто междометия. Значит, ничего страшного. Особенно, если изменить написание.

Answer (score 2):

**Блять** - не междометие, а инфинитив (неопределенная форма глагола). Корень *бля*, суффикс *ть*. Значение по обстоятельствам.
В древнерусском языке :

> **БЛѦ|СТИ**
> 1.Блуждать, плутать.
> 2. Пустословить, болтать нелепости, хулить...
> (Словарь ДРЯ 11-14 вв)

Дополнение.

> Морфологически вводные слова и вводные сочетания слов выражаются или специальными словами, которые употребляются только как вводные (итак, пожалуйста, по-видимому, впрочем, следовательно, по-моему, по-твоему и т. д., во-первых, во-вторых и т. д.),или словами разных частей речи в особом употреблении. Сюда относятся:
> г) глаголы в спрягаемой форме (признаюсь, извините, разумеется, говорят, видите ли и т. д.), **в форме инфинитива и инфинитивного сочетания** (признаться, знать, кстати сказать и т. д.)...

[Ссылка](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/160/вводные)

С ума сойти, озвереть, умереть не встать, офигеть, а также совершенно нецензурные примеры. Их стараются употреблять при оценке ситуации.
Вариант с буквой д может служить обращением или вводной характеристикой субъекта, о котором идет речь.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52093/discussion-on-answer-by--grantum-----).

Answer (score 2):

Ужас! Уже даже матерный язык не знают.

*Б--дь* - это существительное. Междометием оно будет, только если "дь" отбросить вовсе (усечение корня встречается в разговорной речи: *секунда-сек, презерватив-презик* и т. д.). Инфинитивом для глагола данного корня будет *б--дствовать*.

В качестве междометия в разговорной речи встречается использование слово почти из любой части речи, но написание при этом неизменно.

Comment: Марк, они уверены, что знают. Ведь "блядь" никого не обижает, т.е. это уже достаточный повод для её правомерного существования. К тому же, так даже Т.Н. Толстая пишет и поясняет такое написание в лучших традициях Я-поисковика: "есть "блядь" - распутная женщина, а есть "блять" и это междометие". И всё. Таким людям ничего не докажешь, мне кажется.

Comment: Не надо ничего доказывать. Я лично эти слова (с **т** и с **д**) первый раз в жизни вот в этой теме пишу, заради прикола. И мне безразлично, как вы их будете писать в дальнейшем. Но пишите, пишите, без точек и звездочек, только оставьте, пожалуйста, людям с ч/ю возможность побаловаться инфинитивом))) Плюс за вопрос я поставил, кстати...

Comment: @Дарья Gilraen, слова "чёрт", "блин", тоже могут использоваться как междометия. В известном монологе Галыгина, в качестве междометия использовалось слово "сука", но орфография при этом не меняется. Да и само по себе, изменять орфографию в месте, где это не проявляется фонетически бессмысленно.

Comment: Страсти-то какие...

>Ведь "блядь" никого не обижает,   
   
Гм... За всех-то не говорите.